# No. of strings in format string specifier

Tags: c, string, io

I have seen this way of using *combination* of strings in printf and scanf statements.

```
int a;
printf("Printing" "using" "multiple" "strings" "%d", a);
// The above is just an example, some usage that I saw was for printing specific integer types like int_32
// uint32_t var; printf("Value is %" PRTu32, var);
```

I always thought that we could only use a single string as a format specifier. Like as written in the definition of printf function it seems format can point to only one string.

> int printf ( const char * format, ... );

So out of curiosity I tried the following code and it ran successfully!

```
char arr[] = "Hello " "World";
printf("%s",arr);      // Output - Hello World
```

Could anyone explain how this concatenation thing works and what is the correct way of doing it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Concatenation works like concatenation!  The compiler sees `"foo" "bar"` and treats it the same as `"foobar"`.

Comment: See 5.1.1.2 of https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2. "Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give a space or no space in between two string literals it concatenates the string literals.

That's one of the C feature: This is defined by the ISO C standard, adjacent string literals are automatically combined/concatinated into a single one.